# Django Tiny_MCE and FileBrowser leading ../../../

Tags: django, tinymce, django-filebrowser

Hi Im using Filebrowser for Django and also TinyMCE. I include TinyMCE in my admin text area editor by adding a admin template to folder media in my templates with filename base_site.html

Now when I add a image with filebrowser, tiny_mce adds a leading ../../../../ before /media/uploads/etc/image.jpg

Any ideas why? I guess its some URL thats not set correct. But im not sure if its tiny_mce or filebrowser.

Comment: What settings for filebrowser do you have set?
http://code.google.com/p/django-filebrowser/wiki/Settings

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE has an option to avoid converting urls to what seems to be relative urls. You need to put the following on your configuration:

```
remove_script_host : false,
convert_urls : false,
```

Check out this thread: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=642

Comment: For Django Filebrowser + TinyMCE, these settings need to be added to `TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = { ... }` in `settings.py`.